# Dynamic map sidebar with info from marker upon click

Tags: leaflet, javascript, html, css, leaflet-plugins

I am new to Leaflet, HTML, CSS and Java. I am using leaflets maps and I want to create a sidebar that is active when a marker is clicked or active when a clicked in the sidebar, so far I have had no luck at all. I have tried to do similar to this but I want defined markers lat and long http://jsfiddle.net/BPuQ9/8/ but have had no luck

I have a JSfiddle file here: https://jsfiddle.net/Niall2110/yphxqzu2/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og==" crossorigin=""></script>

<style>
    html, body, #map {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    margin-left:10%;
    padding:0;
}
#overlay {
    position:absolute;
    width:30%;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}


</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id = "map"></div>
<div id="overlay"></div>

<script>


var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [48,14],
    zoom: 7,
   animate: true, duration: 1
});

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
   maxZoom: 18,
   attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a 
href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
    '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
    'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
id: 'mapbox.streets'
}).addTo(map);

L.marker([49, 14]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("<b><font size='6'>Headline</font></b><br />info<br //> <img src=''> <a href= '' target='_blank'><button>Source</button></a> ").openPopup();
$('#overlay').append(
        '<div class="item" id="' + marker._leaflet_id + '">marker ' + marker._leaflet_id + ' - <a href="#" class="remove" id="' + marker._leaflet_id + '">remove</a></div>');



</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Could you please add a minimal working example of your current code to the question, since links are subject to change. Also, please expand a bit on what you tried so far to achieve your goal.

Comment: Erik, thanks for getting back to me. I want to have defined markers that once clicked on they show up and appear on the sidebar and when the markers clicked on the sidebar they show up on the map.

Comment: Do you want sidebar to be open all the time or only on click? Do you want to close sidebar upon click on sidebar?

Comment: Sidebar needs to be open permanently

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about "sidebar that is active when a marker is clicked or active when a clicked in the sidebar"? It's not clear what you mean by "active" and what should happen if you click on sidebar.

Comment: I will have many markers placed on the map. I want a sidebar to the left of the map that contains information regarding the markers. So when a certain marker is clicked the relevant information will be displayed on the sidebar and on a popup from the marker. I want to be able to scroll through the sidebar and when a certain source of information is clicked on the sidebar it will go to this point on the marker. So basically the sidebar is a constant feed of information that is linked to marker. An advanced example is https://liveuamap.com which is similar to what I want to achieve. Thank you

Comment: Please edit your question and add all your additional explanations to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Solution below is not complete solution with all the required bells and whistles (specially CSS styles are lame), it's just a first step in the right direction.

There is simple function `createMarker` for creating markers with all the desired properties (position, title, text, image, source link). Function creates marker in `markerLayer` with the following properties:

- Basic info text (title, text, link) is created. It's the same for popup and sidebar.
- Popup is created with info text.
- Mouse click event handler is created for marker. This handler upon mouse click adds HTML element to the sidebar, again with two clickable elements. One is info text, which upon click puts corresponding marker to the center of the map and bounces it (Leaflet.SmoothMarkerBouncing plugin). The other is `Remove` element which upon click removes the whole element from the sidebar.

Working JSFiddle is available at https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/ox43cbth/5/

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
  <link crossorigin="" href="lib/leaflet/leaflet.css"rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="lib/leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/Leaflet.SmoothMarkerBouncing/leaflet.smoothmarkerbouncing.js"></script>
  <style>
    html, body, #map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      margin-left: 10%;
      padding:0;
    }
    #sidebar {
      position: absolute;
      width: 30%;
      height: 100%;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    }
    .sidebarElement {
      padding: 6px;
      display: table;
      width: 95%;
    }
    .infoSidebarElement {
      display: table-cell;
      cursor: pointer;
      width: 90%;
    }
    .removeSidebarElement {    
      display: table-cell;
      text-align: right;
      cursor: pointer;
    }  //closing bracket was missing (had to add some more letters, otherwise unable to submit)
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="sidebar"></div>
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
  var map = L.map('map', {
      center: [48,14],
      zoom: 7,
     animate: true, duration: 1
  });
  
  L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
     maxZoom: 18,
     attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
      '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
      'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    id: 'mapbox.streets'
  }).addTo(map);

  markerLayer = L.layerGroup([]).addTo(map);
   
  function createMarker(coords, title, info, image, source) {
    var marker, content;
  
    content = '<b><font size="6">' + title + '</font></b><br/>' + info + '<br> <img src="' + image + '"><a href="' + source + '" target="_blank"><button>Source</button></a>'
    marker = L.marker(coords).addTo(markerLayer);
    marker.bindPopup(content);
    
    marker.on('click', function(evt) {
      var id = L.Util.stamp(evt.target);
      if (document.getElementById(id) != null) return; 
      var sidebarElement, infoPart, removePart;
      sidebarElement = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'sidebarElement', document.getElementById('sidebar'));
      sidebarElement.id = id;
      infoPart = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'infoSidebarElement', sidebarElement);
      infoPart.innerHTML = content;
      L.DomEvent.on(infoPart, 'click', function(evt) {
        var marker = markerLayer.getLayer(this.id);
        marker.closePopup();
        map.panTo(marker.getLatLng());
        marker.bounce(3);
      }, sidebarElement);
      removePart = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'removeSidebarElement', sidebarElement);
      removePart.innerHTML = 'Remove';
      L.DomEvent.on(removePart, 'click', function(evt) {
        markerLayer.getLayer(this.id).closePopup();
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
      }, sidebarElement);
    });
  }
  
  createMarker([49, 14], 'Title 1', 'Info 1', '', ''); 
  createMarker([47, 12], 'Title 2', 'Info 2', '', ''); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is [this plugin: leaflet sidebar](https://github.com/Turbo87/leaflet-sidebar).  There's also [version 2](https://github.com/Turbo87/sidebar-v2), which is more interactive.  I recommend playing with these sidebars.  The github repositories have great instructions on how to get them up and running on your page, even as a newbie. For example, using [sidebar](https://github.com/Turbo87/leaflet-sidebar), once you've added the sidebar, you can set the content of the sidebar using an eventlistener on your marker:

```
let marker = L.marker( [lat,lng] , {options} ).addTo(map)
marker.addEventListener("click", function(){
   sidebar.setContent('Whatever content you want displayed here');
}, false)
```

If you want content in your sidebar to link back to your map, you can set the text of your sidebar content as a variable with your HTML content:

```js
let sidebarContent = "<p>This marker that you've clicked is at x and y
    location, has historical significance X, and is sister cities with 
    <a id="sisterCity">this city</a>.</p>"
```

Then you can grab your link that you've IDed, and put a function on it that does something with your map:

```
let sisterCityLink = document.querySelector('#sisterCity');
sisterCity.addEventListener('click', function(){
  map.setView( [sisterCityLat, sisteCityLng] )
  // map.setZoom....
  // sidebar.SetContent(sisterCityConent)....
  // etc....
}, false)
```